# Fibonacci, Golden and Logarithmic Spirals clarifications

Tags: geometry

I have been looking at references for Math Appreciation and I have a few clarifications without having to go in the very advanced topics

1.) Is the Fibonacci Spiral different from the golden spiral? In my understanding, the Fibonacci spiral becomes very similar to the golden spiral as the number of squares increase, but I have seen references that pertain to the Fibonacci spiral as the golden spiral, so I am not sure what to use.

2.) Is the golden spiral a logarithmic spiral? I know that the "Fibonacci Spiral" is not a true logarithmic spiral because they are made from quarter circle arcs, a logarithmic spiral constantly increases instead of increasing every quarter circle turn. The golden spiral is also made from the rectangles and has a similar approach to the "Fibonacci Spiral".

Comment: does [Wiki][1] answer ? 

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral

Comment: Im referring to this reference as https://www.quora.com/Is-the-golden-spiral-the-same-as-the-fibonacci-spiral#:~:text=No.,they%20are%20not%20the%20same.&text=Technically%2C%20both%20of%20these%20are,so%20often%20found%20in%20nature.

Comment: Where making a golden spiral is made from cutting the golden rectangle, then still making circular arcs. Thus the size of the radius is constant for parts of the spiral, whereas in my understanding the radius gradually increases for a logarithmic spiral